# How do I "cat and follow" a file?

Tags: files, pipe, cat, tail, open-files

A file is being sequentially downloaded by `wget`.

If I start unpacking it with `cat myfile.tar.bz2 | tar -xj`, it may unpack correctly or fail with "Unexpected EOF", depending on what is faster.

How to "cat and follow" a file, i.e. output content of the file to stdout, but don't exit on EOF, instead keep subsribed to that file and continue outputting new portions of the data, exiting only if the file is closed by writer and not re-opened within N seconds.

---

I've created a script [cat_and_follow](https://gist.github.com/vi/340a2dba88ff14abfa4f) based on @arielCo's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139873/22222) that also terminates the `tail` when the file is not being opened for writing anymore.

Comment: I think you're looking for the `tail` command with its follow option.

Comment: `tail` works with binary files as well?

Comment: You might also like `less +F`...

Comment: I know you found your solution, but I have a question, why not simply do: `wget ... && tar xjvf ...`

Comment: @JosephR., 1. To save up time by parallelizing; 2. To even up system load (avoiding/minimizing resource-intensive full throttle unpacking phase); 3. To avoid remembering about the "unpack" command later (or scheduling it) or typing chained command in the first place (when I'm not yet sure that I want to unpack it).

Comment: @JosephR., 4. To use the time spent on typing `&& tar ...` for downloading as well; 5. To be able to cancel unpacking without cancelling downloading easily.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the "Answer" section. As a general rule, answering your own question is fine and encouraged but since it was based on the accepted answer I just changed your wording to clarify.

Comment: @Vi. Yes, tail just works on bytes, which means binary files are fine.

Comment: See also: [Open `less` scrolled to the end](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373461/open-less-scrolled-to-the-end/373540#373540)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
tail +1f file
```

I tested it on Ubuntu with the LibreOffice source tarball while `wget` was downloading it:

```
tail +1f libreoffice-4.2.5.2.tar.xz | tar -tvJf -
```

It also works on Solaris 10, RHEL3, AIX 5 and Busybox 1.22.1 in my Android phone (use `tail +1 -f file` with Busybox).

Comment: Will it automatically exit when downloading is finished? I expect that "follower" to scan `/proc/*/fd/` periodically and check whether the file is closed for good.

Comment: I didn't expect that `tail` works with binray files...

Comment: Created a script that does scanning /proc/../fd and auto-termination.

Comment: @Vi. It's great that you solved your problem. Can you share your solution?

Comment: @Schism, It's already shared on Github Gists. See the link in the edited question.

Comment: You don't need GNU tail, I believe the `-f` option is standard. However, it won't terminate automatically when the download is finished.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right - I tested it on Solaris, adjusting the switches for compatibility. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: In Ubuntu `tail +1f` does not work. You have to do `tail -n +1`

Comment: Agreed, I've just tried Ubuntu 16.04, and it tried to read `+1` as a file.  So it seems `tail -n+1 -f` is necessary.

Comment: What does the `+1` do?

Comment: @GabrielStaples `+n` = start printing at the n-th line (or byte). https://linux.die.net/man/1/tail

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `cat` is not aware that the file is still being appended. As soon as `cat` encounters the (current) end of the file it exits.

You have to make `wget` write to a pipe (or FIFO) in order to avoid this.

```
wget -O - http://... | tar -xjf -
```

Comment: Or `curl`, which outputs to stdout by default. And (1) `-f -` is redundant, `tar` reads from stdin by default, and (2) most `tar`s can detect the compression automatically, so the `j` is often unnecessary.  `curl http://... | tar x`

Comment: This will download without saving the unpacked file. Also it will hinder continuing the download in case of bad network.

Comment: @Vi. You can save the file by using `tee` like this: `curl http://… | tee ….tbz | tar -xj`, but resuming the download gets more complicated than just invoking the same command again.

Answer (score 12):

To **read and follow** a file from the beginning until interrupted:

```
tail -fn +1 file
```

To demonstrate that, try this (assuming Bash with GNU Coreutils):

```
(while true; do printf . >> /tmp/file; sleep 1; done)&
tail -fn +1 /tmp/file  # (Ctrl-C to interrupt, of course, or otherwise kill it.)
kill %  # Kills the while-loop.
```

*(Note: The `+1f` mentioned by others is interpreted as a filename, at least in the GNU `tail` command.)*

The above works for a single file. Concatenation of multiple files would not be able to follow all of them deterministically, without hanging on the first. To ‘*cat and follow*’, following only the last file, one can use [process substitution](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). Here's another demonstration:

```
printf file1 > /tmp/file1; printf file2 > /tmp/file2
(while true; do printf . | tee -a /tmp/file{1,2} > /dev/null; sleep 1; done)&
cat /tmp/file1 <(tail -fn +1 /tmp/file2)  # (Interrupt or kill it.)
kill %  # Kills the while-loop.
```

Comment: This worked for me while `tail +1f file` didn't.

Comment: This answer is much better than `tail +1f` when combining it with other options such as `--pid`

Answer (score 0):

### With `less +F` [My favorite]

*Tested on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 with GNU `less` version 487, as shown by `less --version`.*

You can also use `less`:

```bsh
less -N +F path/to/some/growing/log_file.log
```

You may also want to follow the *name* of a file instead of its file descriptor by adding the `--follow-name` option:

```bsh
# [My favorite command overall]
less -N --follow-name +F path/to/some/growing/log_file.log
```

This is useful to follow the file named `log_file.log`, for instance, even when a rotating log system renames this file to `log_file.log.1` as it rotates to a new log file to begin logging. WithOUT `--follow_name`, `less` would continue to follow the file `log_file.log.1`, which is now frozen and not growing, whereas WITH `--follow-name`, `less`, will see the name changed and automatically open and begin following the new `log_file.log` file. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196168/does-less-have-a-feature-like-tail-follow-name-f/196349#196349).

The `-N` shows line numbers. The `+` causes `less` to run the command right after the `+` symbol when it opens. The `F` command causes it to continually read and load (ie: "follow") the end of the file, which is particularly useful to see growing log files grow. Pressing `F` (ie: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) while `less` is open is identical to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>.

To interrupt and stop this continual loading effect while `less` is running, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. Now you can go back to being able to use `less` like normal, scrolling up and down to view data as you desire. Then press <kbd>q</kbd> to exit, like normal. Or, you can resume following the file by typing `F` (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>).

Note: to just open in `less` and jump to the end of the file but NOT continually load ("follow") the new contents as they are added, use the `G` command (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> in `less` if `less` is already running) instead of `F` (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> if `less` is already running):

```bsh
less -N +G path/to/some/growing/log_file.log
```

### With `tail -f` [Best option on BusyBox]

Note that if using `tail` on a regular Linux machine, *not* an embedded Linux machine with a BusyBox implementation of `tail`, you can use `tail`'s `--follow=name` option to do the equivalent of `less`'s `--follow-name` option described above.

*The following was tested with BusyBox v1.31.1, as shown by `busybox --help`.*

The `less +F` option isn't available on embedded Linux systems running busybox, so for these systems use `tail -f` instead:

```bsh
# Just show new contents as they come into the file
tail -f path/to/some/growing/log_file.log

# Also print the entire file first, starting at the first line (`+1`), before
# following and loading new contents continually
tail +1 -f path/to/some/growing/log_file.log
```

It's not quite as convenient as `less`, but it still works just fine. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the output. Then you can scroll up in the terminal to see previous lines in case you need to "pause" the output and view something more-closely. To "resume" viewing the file, press the <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> key of course to recall your previous command so you can easily run the same `tail -f` command again.

Some other useful options on BusyBox are `-s SECONDS` and possibly `-F`. Ex:

```bsh
# only check and load new contents at the end of the file every 2 seconds
tail -f -s 2 path/to/some/growing/log_file.log
```

Here is the full help menu:

> ```
> # tail --help
> BusyBox v1.31.1 (2021-11-20 02:33:23 UTC) multi-call binary.
>
> Usage: tail [OPTIONS] [FILE]...
>
> Print last 10 lines of each FILE (or stdin) to stdout.
> With more than one FILE, precede each with a filename header.
>
>     -f      Print data as file grows
>     -c [+]N[kbm]    Print last N bytes
>     -n N[kbm]   Print last N lines
>     -n +N[kbm]  Start on Nth line and print the rest
>     -q      Never print headers
>     -s SECONDS  Wait SECONDS between reads with -f
>     -v      Always print headers
>     -F      Same as -f, but keep retrying
>
> N may be suffixed by k (x1024), b (x512), or m (x1024^2).
> ```

### With `watch` [also works on BusyBox]

Here is another option. This also works fine in BusyBox:

```bsh
# Continually view the last 20 messages of the log file every 1 second
watch -n 1 'tail -n 20 path/to/some/growing/log_file.log'
```

### References

1. I first learned about `less +F` here: [Open `less` scrolled to the end](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373461/open-less-scrolled-to-the-end/373540#373540)
2. I first learned about `less +G` here: [Open `less` scrolled to the end](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373461/open-less-scrolled-to-the-end/373465#373465)
3. Where I learned about less's `--follow-name` option: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196349/114401