# Open `less` scrolled to the end

Tags: less

Is there a way to open `less` and have it scroll to the end of the file? I'm always doing `less app.log` and then pressing `G` to go to the bottom.

I'm hoping there's something like `less --end` or `less -exec 'G'`.

Comment: See also: [How do I "cat and follow" a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139866/114401)

Answer (score 409, accepted):

`less +G app.log`

`+` will run an initial command when the file is opened

`G` jumps to the end

When multiple files are in play, `++` applies commands to every file being viewed. Not just the first one. For example, `less ++G app1.log app2.log`.

Comment: Great, this also works for my use case: Go to the first line that says "abc": `less +/"abc"`

Comment: Works great for my https://ohmyz.sh `alias hist="omz_history -E | less -i +G"`.

With this you get a command line history with human readable timestamps `-E` and `less` being scrolled to the bottom thanks to `+G` with the youngest entries, and can then scroll up with the arrow keys or search case insensitive right away thanks to `-i`.

Comment: `G` is great, but I really think `F` is better, as [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373540/114401) states. Pressing `F` while `less` is open is identical to pressing `Ctrl` + `End`. It will continually read and load the end of the file. This is very useful for a growing log file.

Comment: @alper as default, less "scrolls" to top

Answer (score 84):

```
less +F filename
```

will go to the end *and* continually load the latest contents of the file.

From less man page:

> `F` Scroll forward, and keep trying to read when the end of file is
> reached. Normally this command would be used when already at the end
> of the file. It is a way to monitor the tail of a file which is
> growing while it is being viewed. (The behavior is similar to the
> "`tail -f`" command.)

Comment: Note that pressing `F` while `less` is open is identical to pressing `Ctrl` + `End`. It will continually read and load the end of the file. This is very useful for a growing log file.

Answer (score 12):

From the less man page:

> If a command line option begins with +, the remainder of that option is taken to be an initial command to less.  For example, +G tells less to
>                 start at the end of the file rather than the beginning, and +/xyz tells it to start at the first occurrence of "xyz" in the file.  As  a  special  case, + acts like +g; that is, it starts the display at the specified line number (however, see the caveat under the "g"
>                 command above).  If the option starts with ++, the initial command applies to every file being viewed, not just the first one.  The +  command
>                 described previously may also be used to set (or change) an initial command for every file.