# Output large file entirely in follow mode similiar to tail -f

Tags: cat, tail, less

Is there a command to output a large file and follow on directly in the shell stdout?

I am aware of `less +F` or I could simply use `tail` with an ultimately high `n` like `tail -f -n1000000` if the file is already big, when I call `tail` but I was wondering if there is a proper way to handle this.

`less` is not handy in my situation because the files I handle contain carriage returns and the like, which `less` displays instead of moving the cursor. `cat` heads the `CR`but does not follow and `tail -f` does not give me the whole picture... basically I guess I am looking for `cat -f <single-file>`

Comment: `tail -f` doesn't truncate output, it will just keep displaying whatever has come so far while still displaying what was there earlier in the terminal. How would your `cat -f` handle multiple files?

Comment: It needs not. Actually I use cat most of the time to display a single file not to concatenate multiple files. My bad.I will try to clarify my question further.

Comment: @fra-san thanks for the link but the other question differs in tail being invoked when the file is still small, if I am not mistaken. My use case involves that I want to follow a file that is already big before I make my call.

Comment: (Deleted my comment because the solution proposed [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139866/315749) throws an error if two or more files are given as arguments; it should be `tail -n +1 -f file`). That will print the full file and will keep following it, regardless of how big it is. I guess I'm not getting how this is different from what your question is asking for.

Comment: Mixed up `-nx` and `-n +x`. Terribly sorry. Would love to accept your answer as solution if you follow up on your comment. Or mark as duplicate if I found a matching question. Open to suggestions :-)

Comment: Considering that questions are often considered duplicates if they share the same answers (regardless of the specific issues they try to solve), I'd personally make this a duplicate of [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139866/315749) one.

Comment: How about `less -r +F`?

Comment: @fra-san I'd suggest you make it an answer. The other question uses a syntax that will not work for everybody and it relates another problem. If I were trying to solve the OP's question I'd rather have the straight answer here and not have to get to the comments of the accepted solution to find out the right syntax is `-n +1 -f`.

Comment: @Björn instead of tailing by lines (which is causing `tail` to pointlessly "parse" your file, unlike `cat`), tail it by bytes: `tail -fc+1 file`.

Comment: @user414777, I don't expect `tail -fc+1` and `tail -fn+1` will be much different, the first one tells `tail` to skip 0 byte before starting the `tail -f` loop and the second one to skip 0 line before starting the `tail -f` loop. In both cases, that just tells `tail` to enter the `tail -f` loop straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection of suggestions:

- From [How do I "cat and follow" a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139866/315749) (noting that the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139873/315749), there, uses the obsolete `tail -[num][bcl][f] [file]` syntax<sup>1</sup>):

  ```
  tail -n +1 -f file
  ```

  It prints the whole `file` and then keeps following it.

  - As noted by [user414777](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/414777/user414777) in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634471/output-large-file-entirely-in-follow-mode-similiar-to-tail-f#comment1188212_634471), `tail` doesn't need to care about newline characters in your case and starting from the first *byte* may be a better option:

    ```
    tail -c +1 -f file
    ```
- As noted by [Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski) in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634471/output-large-file-entirely-in-follow-mode-similiar-to-tail-f#comment1188160_634471), an alternative could be:

  ```
  less -r +F
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>See, for reference, the compatibility notes in the [GNU tail documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html).</sub>